# How to use Google Drive SDK in Android project with hardcoded credentials

Tags: android, google-drive-api

How can I hardcode credentials to my Google Drive Service so users of the app will always get acces to my files without auth?

I have found solution using Java SKD but these libraries doesn't work well with Android: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#use_service_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts

Are there any examples of successful attempts of similar tasks?

Comment: just hardcode your api_key at this line ,`private static final String API_KEY = "the_api_key_of_the_project";` and its done.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't allow to modify files via Drive web app as I want to. Thanks for response.

Comment: Would this grant access to the App's [AppFolder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) without the need to ask for the user permission? I'm asking because I was trying to store each user's preferences that way but couldn't find how to remove the Google Drive message asking for permission. To me, that's just bad user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found solution for my problem.

Of course my app is an Android one, I dont'n want make user to log in/use any credentials to connect to my Drive, and lastly I can manipulate files using default Drive web app.

1. Seps need to be taken: Create *service account* as in [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#google_apis_console_project_service_accounts)
   example.
2. Download private key *API Access site* and put it eg. in
   assets folder.
3. Download and import these libraries:

   - google-api-client-1.13.2-beta.jar
   - google-api-client-android-1.13.2-beta.jar
   - google-api-services-drive-v2-rev60-1.13.2-beta.jar
   - google-http-client-1.13.1-beta.jar
   - google-http-client-android-1.13.1-beta.jar
   - google-http-client-gson-1.13.1-beta.jar
   - google-http-client-jackson2-1.13.1-beta.jar
   - google-oauth-client-1.13.1-beta.jar
   - gson-2.1.jar
   - guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
   - jackson-core-2.0.5.jar
   - jsr305-1.3.9.jar
4. Implement Drive service getter:

   ```
   public Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
       HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
       JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
           .setTransport(httpTransport)
           .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
           .setServiceAccountId(G_SERVICE_EMAIL)
           .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
           .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(PKC_12_FILE)
           .build();
       Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
           .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
           .build();
       return service;
   }
   ```

   Where **G_SERVICE_EMAIL** is email address from *API Access site* and **PKC_12_FILE** is previously downloaded private key.
5. Allow your service to access folder from your Drive: in sharing options of the folder in [Drive app](https://drive.google.com) allow user with email: **G_SERVICE_EMAIL** read/write access.

   ### PKC FILE INTEGRATION

   ```
   private File getTempPkc12File() throws IOException {
       InputStream pkc12Stream = getAssets().open("this-is-your-unique-hash-privatekey.p12");
       File tempPkc12File = File.createTempFile("temp_pkc12_file", "p12");
       OutputStream tempFileStream = new FileOutputStream(tempPkc12File);

       int read = 0;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
       while ((read = pkc12Stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
           tempFileStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
       }
       return tempPkc12File;
   }
   ```

Comment: How did you integrate the PKC_12_FILE into this? I am having a lot of problems using this in android. For example I am having trouble accessing the file that I downloaded (where do i put the file, or do you access it from /res/raw or /assets and convert from an inputstream?)

Comment: I've added my way of integrating this file. Simply put it to assets directory and use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this. If you have an access token you can always add it as a URL parameter `access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN` to the request URL.