# Login to a specific Google Drive account through code

Tags: android, google-drive-api

**Is it possible to login into a google account from an android device through code?**

The reason i'm asking is this:

I want to use google drive to store the contents for an app, and then from the app read the folder structure of the GDrive contents and download whatever is necessary.

I want to hardcode the username and password for that particular account in my code and login.

Is it possible?

I have gone through various things available on the web including the Google Drive APIs but have not been able to figure out how to login to some specific account.

I am not looking for a complete solution, a nudge in the right direction would be fine!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497888/how-to-use-google-drive-sdk-in-android-project-with-hardcoded-credentials - here is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Username/password, aka basic authorization is not supported. You need to go through OAuth 2.0 flow. `GoogleAccountCredential` intent does much of the work for you. See the [Android quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android).

If you don't want user interaction and want to create a Google Drive account for your app to serve files, you may embed an encrypted access token and a refresh token into your application and init a credential object with the embedded tokens. Please review security concerns before taking such a decision:

```
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setClientSecrets("...")
    ....
    .build();

credential.setAccessToken(storedAccessToken);
credential.setRefreshToken(storedRefreshToken)
```

Comment: Thank you, but if i go according to the quickstart sample i would have to choose an account that has been already added on my device. I need to upload/download from a specific google drive account without adding it as an account on my device.

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit to you a second option.