# Android open google drive with intent with specified account

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, google-drive-android-api

I have multiple account set up in my Google drive

`account1@gmail.com`
`account2@gmail.com`

and I want to open the google drive with `account2@gmail.com` through intent.
I'm able to open the Google Drive App by using below function.

```
fun startOpenGoogleDriveApp() {
    try {
        val intent = activity.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs")
        startActivity(intent)
    }catch (e:Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Tried using `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER,"account2@gmail.com")`, but did not work.

Is it possible to send/specify the account in the intent extras? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may refer with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497888). You may need to create a service account as in [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) documentation. Also from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017108), if you don't want user interaction and want to create a Google Drive account for your app to serve files, you may embed an encrypted access token and a refresh token into your application and init a credential object with the embedded tokens.

Comment: Please Sri, check my answer. I was also in this problem once. I posted the everything I knew from my research.

Answer (score 0):

I'm neither familiar with `kotlin` nor with the method, you're using. I'm telling you the way mentioned exactly in the docs and with which I'm familiar.

```
//Starts the sign-in process and initializes the Drive client.
    public void signIn() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
        startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
    }

/**
 * Handles resolution callbacks.
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fab), R.string.sign_in_alert, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fab), R.string.sign_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Continues the sign-in process, initializing the DriveResourceClient with the current
 * user's account.
 */
private void initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {
    mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
    mDriveResourceClient.getAppFolder().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DriveFolder driveFolder) {
            onDriveClientReady();
            // CONTINUE THE TASK
        }
    });
}

abstract void onDriveClientReady();
```

Now, put this in an `abstract` activity class then, extend that from the **Main Activity Class**.

This code is **exception-safe**, if the user cancels the sign-in, you'll be able to terminate reaching the next line of code from `onActivityResult`.The user will be displayed the sign-in options, to choose one account for sign-in. If it comes `RESULT_OK` at `onActivityResult`, that means he has signed-in.

The next line of code will try to initialize the `DriveClient` asynchronously (Here I wanted the `appfolder` only, so tried `getAppFolder` and `Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER`, you'll set it up as you need.). When the drive client is successfully initialized, you'll get the `DriveFolder` from the `onSuccess` method.

**Dependencies**

```
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev114-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
```

**Further Help and the Docs**

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/android
- https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder
- https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file
- https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/
- https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/wizard?api=drive.googleapis.com

**Note**
I always keep backup of my application codes. If you want to see the whole class I'm using, see this :

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wphtpe3ebd62xd/LoginActivity.java?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Exploitr's answer worked for me, however the dependencies needed a little finagling to get working. The gradle dependencies will work as of 2024 with the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.1.0'
```

You must also create an application on https://console.cloud.google.com/ with the google drive scopes you require, with a matching package name, and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. Don't be put off if it take a day or so for google to recognize your app. For more information you can also read through: https://dev.to/mesadhan/google-drive-api-with-android-4m2e