# Accessing google drive in android

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I am making and android app which downloads a particular file from Google Drive, reformats the data in the file and then displays it to the user.
I have used the Google Drive API. In the app, instead of asking the User to select an account, I want to hard code a Google Account Username and Password through which the file on the Drive is downloaded. This should happen without the user's interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to hardcode your account data - just use Service account

[How to use Google Drive SDK in Android project with hardcoded credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497888/how-to-use-google-drive-sdk-in-android-project-with-hardcoded-credentials) - here the solution.