# Google Drive api android how to login and logout from my drive account with hard code without user interaction?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In my drive app registration activity  when user put his/her email-id and hit register i want to login to my google drive account i will give email id,password login and share some files with user's given email-id and logout . And then start home activity.

I know about drive account picker but not getting how to login and logout with hardcode. and also to login how to give my password because user will be unaware of all these things i cannot use account picker. After logging out my account details should not be there in user's mobile account manager, gmail or anywhere else. Any one suggest how can i achive this or any alternative way to do it.

In simple words

1. How to login to drive account using my given email and password with Hard code.
2. After sharing files logout from my account with hard code.

Comment: It can be done with a Google Service Account. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497888/how-to-use-google-drive-sdk-in-android-project-with-hardcoded-credentials?lq=1

Comment: @ user1904954 If you have implemented it please post your answer it will be really helpful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this can all be done on Android. You will need to create a web app to do the sharing.

So ..

1. your Android app will call a REST API on your web app, passing the email address
2. your web app will retrieve a stored refresh token for your account
3. it will use the refresh token to request an access token
4. it will use the access token to share the files with the email address