# Android upload/download text files from sdcard to Google Drive with Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to implement Google Drive upload/download txt file to my Android app using Google Play Services, but I don't find a right way to do it.

In dropbox is very easy:

```
File file = new File("working-draft.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/magnum-opus.txt", inputStream,
                            file.length(), null, null);
Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
```

But for Google Drive with Google Play Services I have not found a simple way like that. Do you know how to?

By the way, I would like to use my own credentials (google service account) instead an user account, what is the way to implement it with Google Play Services?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a [look here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA), it does everything you've mentioned. I don't know about the 'simple' requirement, though. Or go through the official [DEMO code here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos). But it is definitely not a 'two-liner' endeavor.

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to ask you about to implement a service account with this code, I saw here:[hardcoded credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497888/how-to-use-google-drive-sdk-in-android-project-with-hardcoded-credentials) how to implement with other libraries, and it use GoogleCredential to do the auth, with this key method:

.setServiceAccountId(G_SERVICE_EMAIL)
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(PKC_12_FILE)

To not require login. But I don't know how to implement this in your code, because there is no Google Service Account method for GoogleApiClient builder.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about credentials.