# Google drive API with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive-api

I have imported sample google drive api project in eclipse But it shows errors.
Here's the [link](http://postimg.org/image/jq2p5gluh/) of the pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed GooglePlayService from android SDK Manager unser extras. then goto `[your sdk location]\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_li‌​b\libs` and copy past google-play-services.jar available their into your projects libs directory then clean build your project.

Comment: Oh you mean like what I said about him reading this: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the jar in the libs folder, but have you tried right clicking it and selecting "Add to build path"?

Comment: well its a sample project and in "libs" there is "android-support-v4.jar" file. Well I did added it to build path but nothings changed!

Comment: Oh ok  - open the SDK manager and check if you have downloaded the Drive API. If that does not work, please post a pic of your project. It seems from here (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html) that this should be built in on Android, meaning the jar should be built in. Are you on Android Version 23?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497888/how-to-use-google-drive-sdk-in-android-project-with-hardcoded-credentials

Comment: @Quintin Balsdon: I'm having Android SDK's 22.6.4. No Drive API to install in SDK Manager.

Comment: Have you followed the process here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?

Comment: If this does not work, you will need to upgrade to SDK 23 and download play services. Unfortunately I think the upgrade to 23 means a re-install.

Comment: Yeah I think so I need to upgrade. Well I got Google play services.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open the SDK manager and download the Google Play Services under Extras. Then follow the guide here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.

Comment: Have you added the reference library that was downloaded from the Play Services (the jar in the extras file in the sdk file)? 

Do you have this in your manifest:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />